# Error : Refused to get unsafe header "SourceMap"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, source-maps

I am new to webpack. I am getting `Refused to get unsafe header "SourceMap"` or `Refused to get unsafe header "X-SourceMap"` on my production build. In the config section, I am using devtool:inline-source-map for only the development environment.

Comment: By googling i came to know that, this warning occurs when we are trying to read the header from a request which does not exist.